# Как правильно расставить запятые в предложении: "В связи с заявлением и руководствуясь статьей Трудового кодекса РФ приказываю..."?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Как правильно расставить запятые в предложении. Также прошу указать, на какое правило ссылаетесь.

> В связи с заявлением и руководствуясь статьей Трудового кодекса РФ приказываю...

Answer (score 2):

**В связи с заявлением и руководствуясь статьей Трудового кодекса РФ, приказываю...**

Обособленное обстоятельство в начале предложения состоит из двух однородных обстоятельств, выраженных оборотом с производным предлогом ***в связи*** и 
деепричастным оборотом. Обособление связано **с распространенностью обстоятельства.**

У Розенталя рассматривается **тема однородных отношений для обстоятельств, выраженных наречиями и деепричастными оборотами** (с обособлением или без обособления), например: Алёша длинно и как-то прищурив глаза посмотрел на Ракитина. Тихо и как бы капельку побледнев, проговорила Катерина Ивановна.

Примечание. Из примеров видно, что на обособление значительное влияние оказывает структура предложения (обычно автор так строит его, что обстоятельство "не вписывается" в предложение и его приходится обособлять).

Но **точно такой вариант**, как в приведенном предложении (сущ. **с производным предлогом** и деепричастный оборот),  в правилах Розенталя **не рассматривается.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

Comment: Там же у Розенталя находим: **Но для смыслового выделения или для выражения попутного пояснения сочетание наречия с одиночным деепричастием или с деепричастным оборотом может обособляться [см. раздел «Обстоятельства, выраженные наречиями»]: Тихо и как бы капельку побледнев, проговорила Катерина Ивановна (Дост.); В тёмном небе, устало и не сверкая, появились жёлтенькие крапинки звёзд (М. Г.); Виновато и покашливая, мать простилась с нами (Леон.); Недоверчиво, но всё же улыбаясь всем своим существом, он пошёл к ней (Леон.).**

Comment: Спасибо, ответ исправлен и дополнен. Но я бы позволила себе уточнить Розенталя. Обстоятельства в приведенных предложениях просто невозможно не обособить. Поэтому для смыслового выделения автор должен выбрать такую структуру предложения,  чтобы обособление было удобным.